# Using GitHub strategy matrix to select a runner

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to build on several platform, debug and release versions, using GitHub strategy matrix. Each build has a dedicated self-hosted runner.

```
name: Build Gatekeepers
on:
  push:
    branches: master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  Build:
    needs: Update_Checkouts
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [x64_win32_vc14, x64_win32_vc142]
        version: [release, debug]
    runs-on: [ ${{ matrix.os }}, ${{ matrix.version}} ]
    steps:
      - name: Wipe all STAGE folder
        shell: cmd
        run: |
          make wipestage
          rm -rf _*.*
          rm -f Makefile.user
      - name: Setup configuration
        run: make ${{ matrix.os }}
      - name: Make license 
        run: make license 
      - name: Make update 
        run: make update
      - name: Make generate
        run: make generate
      - name: Make build install
        run: make bi.${{ matrix.version }}
```

The line `runs-on: [ ${{ matrix.os }}, ${{ matrix.version}} ]` does not work.

However, if I do `runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}` it will randomly chose one of the two that are aimed for debug and release, and I want a specific runner.

I've tried several variations on the `runs-on: [ ${{ matrix.os }}, ${{ matrix.type }} ]`

I cannot put more than one item, only `matrix.os` or only `matrix.version` does work but does not select the right runner.

Is there a way around this limitation of GitHub? Or am I just not using strategy matrix correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't that start with self-hosted, i.e. `[ "self-hosted", ${{ matrix.os }}, ${{ matrix.type }} ]`? When you say _"does not work"_ is there any more specific information? `jobs.<id>.runs-on` definitely [has access](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability) to the `matrix` context.

Comment: if I  write just `[x64_win32_vc14, release]` it will select the right runner according to tags, so self-hosted might be unecessary but I will add it.

Comment: It says there is an error in the yml file, that's what I mean by it does not work..

You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 42

Comment: You don't have a `matrix.type` configured in your workflow. Only `matrix.os` and `matrix.version`.

Comment: it's typo, the actual workflow has it

Comment: The workflow in the question has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/choosing-the-runner-for-a-job#targeting-runners-in-a-group) provides the answer, the syntax is really important:

> Note: Quotation marks are not required around simple strings like `self-hosted`, but they are required for expressions like  `"${{ inputs.chosen-os }}"`.

The way to make it work is by using quotes:

```
runs-on: [ self-hosted, "${{ matrix.os }}", "${{ matrix.version }}" ]
```